# Doctrine persists old record after page reload

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm really struggling with this, so I hope there is someone out there who can help me...

I have a simple setup in my Symfony 5.3 app: I created a basic Doctrine entity (User), form type (UserFormType), and form model class (UserFormModel) to manage user accounts. Everything works as expected when I submit the form -- the new data persists to the database. What's bizarre is that if I refresh the page or visit a completely different section (like a help page) of the site, Doctrine executes an update query restoring the previous record to the database. The **only** logic that exists to update a user is in the route that I've shared a snippet of below. I'm completely baffled as to why Doctrine is running an update query to restore the previous record, even when visiting an entirely different page of my site...

```
        $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $model);
        $form->handleRequest($this->r);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $model = $form->getData();
            $obj->build($model);

            $this->em->persist($obj);
            $this->em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_user');
        }
```

debug:router output

```
  _preview_error                                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}                             
  _wdt                                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}                                        
  _profiler_home                                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/                                          
  _profiler_search                               ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search                                    
  _profiler_search_bar                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar                                
  _profiler_phpinfo                              ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo                                   
  _profiler_search_results                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results                    
  _profiler_open_file                            ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open                                      
  _profiler                                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}                                   
  _profiler_router                               ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router                            
  _profiler_exception                            ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception                         
  _profiler_exception_css                        ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css                     
  admin                                          ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin                                               
  admin_user                                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/user                                          
  admin_user_crud                                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/user/{action}/{id}                            
  admin_organization                             ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/organization                                  
  admin_organization_crud                        ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/organization/{action}/{id}                    
  admin_plan                                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/plan                                          
  admin_plan_crud                                ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/plan/{action}/{id}                            
  admin_subject                                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/subject                                       
  admin_subject_crud                             ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/subject/{action}/{id}                         
  component_home                                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /{institution}/{component}/home                      
  component_search                               ANY        ANY      ANY    /{institution}/{component}/search/{type}             
  component_request                              ANY        ANY      ANY    /{institution}/{component}/request/{type}/{id}       
  component_summary                              ANY        ANY      ANY    /{institution}/{component}/summary/{type}/{id}       
  help                                           ANY        ANY      ANY    /help                                                
  registrar_home                                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /{institution}/registrar/home                        
  search                                         ANY        ANY      ANY    /search
```

Answer (score 0):

I am so, so dumb... I figured out what was going on. I just realized I had added logic to my UserProvider that pulls data from my company's directory and updates the user's info on each page refresh.